# use req.user inside a normal function and pass to socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I am trying to attach req.user.id (from passport session) to each socket that is created upon connection. Since I cannot access req.user from outside of middleware or a route and as a result get the error of id of undefined,

how do I somehow access this and pass it to my exported socket function?.

I would use app.use( getSocket( ) ) which would allow me to use req.user inside the function but this triggers a connection more than once.

```
// Workspace route

var server   = require('../server.js').serverExport();

var authUser = require('../server.js');
var io       = require('socket.io') ( server );
var socket   = require('./middleware/pusherApi');

function getSocket ( ) { 
    // somehow pass req.user
    var getSocket = socket.connect( io , req.user );
}
getSocket();

// get routes would be below
```

then ,

```
// pusherApi export function

module.exports.connect = function ( io , user ) {
      io.sockets.on('connection', function( socket ) {

            // socket.userId = user;

            console.log('connection added' );
            socket.on('disconnect', function ( data ) {
             });
      });
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?